# Change system sound volume

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am trying to control system sound volume from my WPF application, but nothing changes. I googled for some examples and found one from: [PCVolumeControl](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c#/).

If I try `GetVolume()` it gives me value between 0 and 100. If I use `SetVolume(80)` PC sound doesn't change. Again if I try `GetVolume()` it returns 80.

I am not sure what is wrong in here. According to the web site it might not work with 64 bit, but I didn't see clear answer in there.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following `snippet` from [**this**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/8308f020-b9e6-472c-aaac-93619a8a5a7d/) link, and I had `tested` it in my local system, it is working fine, But i am not sure about, whether it suits for `WPF` or not.

Question Tagged: `VB.NET`

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
            <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
            End Function

            Const WM_APPCOMMAND As UInteger = &H319
            Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As UInteger = &HA
            Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As UInteger = &H9
            Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As UInteger = &H8

            Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * &H10000)
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
                SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN * &H10000)
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
                SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H200EB0, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE * &H10000)
            End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Get known about MediaElement Property.

Following is the link for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume.aspx

Changing volume is like this>>

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" ValueChanged="ValueChanged"/>

private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    media.Volume = e.NewValue;
}
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can change the computer's global volume setting using a `MediaElement`.